# Is using a global user variable a bad practice?

Tags: flash, apache-flex, security, global-variables

I need to have access to the logged in user troughout a flash application. Therefor I'm concidering making the 'user' variable global.

I usually try to avoid global variables, but it seems quite suitable in this case and I'm not the first to concider the active user as a global. I know that systems like drupal also uses a global variable for the logged in user.

I want to know if stackoverflow thinks of this as bad practice or if there are better alternatives.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you use a global variable, you are creating a dependency on that variable in all the modules that use it. So, for example, if you wanted to reuse any of those modules in another project, you would need to take their use of this global variable into account.

Having said that, I don't particularly find it bad design to have a global variable for a user-id. If you wanted to reuse any of the modules that use it, you would want to deal with users anyways, and will probably have that global variable in your new application too.

There are dependency-injection frameworks that could solve this for you. Whether they will add value to your specific project or not depends on many other considerations, and it is really up to you.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I'll keep in mind the dependency that I'm creating. You specifically say "a global variable for a user-id". Does it matter if the global is a simple integer or an object? I need access to more then the user's id.

Comment: Well, the more you put into that global object, the more dependencies you create. Of course, in the end, it is a design decision.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using a MVC framework such as Robotlegs or PureMVC, your problem can be solved by putting the user object into the "M" (model), Proxy for PureMVC for example.
This way you are not creating the global variable per se, but you gain the all advantages of it and can access it from anywhere in you application.

Comment: Thanks for the info. I'm not using an existing framework though. What exactly is the difference between this solution and an actual global?

Comment: The variable is managed by the framework and accessible from everywhere using framework methods. It can also be updated/deleted if needed of course or you can just allow reading (public getter). You can create the UserModel class, and put the (backend retrieved) user object in it.

Answer (score 0):

Global variables are shared by all the threads on a processor, which makes using global variables extremely error prone. To see why this is a problem, Please check http://charm.cs.uiuc.edu/manuals/html/tcharm/2_1.html

Comment: This will only be a problem when the Flash runtime becomes multithreaded, but not now.